# Fubini's theorem: Two dimensional Lebesgue integration (Bivariate uniform distribution probability calculation)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $P= \frac{1}{4}\lambda^2_{|(0,2)^2}$ be the bivariate uniform distribution on $(0,2)^2$, where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

> Calculate the probability $P(A)$ of $A= \{(x,y) \in (0,2)^2 : y ≤ exp(-x)\}$.

How do I even approach this problem? I want to understand every little step.

I know that $P(A) = \int \mathbb{1}_A dP$. Is it possible to express this in the form of $\int \int \cdots dx dy$? Do I have to show that the two dimensions are independent? Do I have to use Fubini's theorem?

Approach:

$\int \mathbb{1}_A d\left(\frac{1}{4}\lambda^2_{|(0,2)^2}\right) = \int \mathbb{1}_{(0,exp(-x)) \times (0,x)} (x,y)  \ d\left(\frac{1}{4}\lambda^2_{|(0,2)^2}\right) = \int_0^1 \int_0^{exp(-x)} y \cdot x \ dy \ dx$

Am I allowed to write it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You note correctly that $P(A) = E[1_{A}] = \int_{\mathbb{R^2}}1_{A}dP$. To evaluate this integral we first compute $dP = \frac{1}{2}\lambda d\lambda$ (check out Radon-Nikodym) and finally
$$\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}1_{A}dP = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^2x\int_0^21_{y\leq e^{-x}}ydydx = \frac{1}{4}\int_0^2xe^{-2x}dx = \frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{5}{4}e^{-4})$$
To justify this you can use an "easier" version of Fubini's theorem, namely Tonelli's theorem, which holds for non-negative functions.

Comment: How do I "compute" the Radon-Nikodym derivate? My first step would be to rewrite $P = 1/4 \left( \lambda_{|(0,2)} \otimes   \lambda_{|(0,2)} \right)$

Comment: Practically, you treat the measure P as if it were a function and you derivate with respect to whatever variable, in this case $\lambda$.

Comment: Can this be understood as a derivate of a normalized identity function on $(0,2)^2$?

Comment: Not completely, this is only the case since $\lambda$ is Lebesgue. Radon-Nikodym is much more general. If you want to unterstand more thoroughly I'm afraid you'll have to read some more in books or Wikipedia.

Comment: I will. For now I'm trying to solve this exercise and your hints have helped me so far. TY!